# send mails via sendgrid

Tags: php, swiftmailer, sendgrid

I'm trying to send mails via sendgrid, here my code :

```
// Setup Swift mailer parameters
        $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.sendgrid.net', 25);
        $transport->setUsername($username);
        $transport->setPassword($password);
        $swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

        // Create a message (subject)
        $message = new Swift_Message($subject);

        // attach the body of the email
        $message->setFrom($from);
        $message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
        $message->setTo($to);
        $message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');

        // send message
        if ($recipients = $swift->send($message, $failures))
        {              
          // This will let us know how many users received this message
          echo 'Message sent out to '.$recipients.' users';exit;
        }
```

I got this error :
Swift_TransportException

Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""

...\swiftMailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(422)

please help me !

Comment: Please contact the vendor of the library for support questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to send the message in one line to see if that works or returns another error. If it returns an error, it's probably a server or authentication issue.

```
$result = $swift->send($message);
```

If that works, you could try the code below and if it works tweak it so it shows your recipients instead of failures.

```
if (!$swift->send($message, $failures))
{
  echo "Failures:";
  print_r($failures);
}
```

Other than that, check if all variables are not empty.

For more examples see: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#quick-reference-for-sending-a-message

**UPDATE**

Sendmail code:

```
//Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

//Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

//Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

//Send the message
$numSent = $mailer->send($message);

printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);
```

Comment: thanks for help, but it doesn't work :( may be some config parameters aren't ok ?

Comment: Did you get another error or the same one? Your code looks fine, perhaps you should try the sendmail function first to see if it's a server issue. I'll update my post with the code.

Comment: It works by this code : 
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance(); but I don't receive any mail ! it means ??

Comment: It probably means that smtp.sendgrid.net isn't supported on your server (external hosts) and mail() for some reason isn't delivered. Does it work to just send mail like this: mail("yourmail@mail.com", "A subject", "A message", "FROM: noreply@mail.com");

Comment: You should ask your host why the SMTP is not working. If you found my help useful please accept my answer.

Comment: It probably means that smtp.sendgrid.net isn't supported on your server (external hosts). thank you mat
this is the problem

Answer (score 5):

(full disclosure: I work at SendGrid as a web developer)

We recently released a new PHP library which may solve some of these problems. We still use Swift but if I recall, the library sets that stuff up for you now, making it a little easier to get rolling.

Don't hesitate to contact us for help, too!

http://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

Comment: awesome. I didn't find however here how to see if the email was sent and if it didn't how to retrieve the errors :(

Comment: For that, you'll want to set an endpoint to receive information from SendGrid's "event notification" system. We'll ping that endpoint every step along the way (if you enable "batch" mode, it'll queue up a batch of JSON to send every minute or so, if you send a lot of Email). The JSON data, if it bounces/etc should return the error as well. Check out http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html

Answer (score 2):

two resons:

1. you may have the authentification data wrong
2. your account might still be provisioned, so you must wait a bit for it to be fully activated

so

- check all the autentification data from app/config/mail.php to match with the data from https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/index.html
- check also not the have a top message/notification on your sendgrid account like:

> Your account is still being provisioned, you may not be able to send
>   emails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just having the same error message with my Symfony 2 config for sendgrid. Hope you've seen this manual: http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/get-started/integrate/examples/symfony-example-using-smtp/

Try changing port to 587. Let me know it works.

Comment: smtp.sendgrid.net isn't supported on my server (external hosts)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you where just too fast? I'm facing the same problem after kickstarting with sendgrid and now with the web-api, i got the real error back "account disabled"...

I did not read the full text after first login - they will review first the account until it gets activated... ok, so i wait ^^