# Fatal error when trying to send email using SwiftMailer and Sendgrid

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer, sendgrid

I'm getting this error when trying to send an email using swiftmailer and the sendgrid smtp

**Fatal error:** *Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""'*

Here's my code :

```
$hdr = new SmtpApiHeader();


// Set all of the above variables
$hdr->addTo($toList);
$hdr->addSubVal('-name-', $nameList);
$hdr->addSubVal('-time-', $timeList);

// Specify that this is an initial contact message
$hdr->setCategory("initial");

// The subject of your email
$subject = 'Example SendGrid Email';

// Where is this message coming from. For example, this message can be from 
// support@yourcompany.com, info@yourcompany.com
$from = array('no-reply@mupiz.com' => 'Mupiz');
$to = array('antonin@noos.fr'=>'AN',"antonin@mupiz.com"=>"AN2s");

$text="Hello -name-
       Thank you for your interest in our products. We have set up an appointment
             to call you at -time- EST to discuss your needs in more detail.

                Regards,

                Fred, How are you?
      ";
$html = "
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello -name-,<br>
       Thank you for your interest in our products. We have set up an appointment
             to call you at -time- EST to discuss your needs in more detail.

                Regards,

                Fred, How are you?<br>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
";

// Your SendGrid account credentials
$username = 'XXXX';
$password = 'XXXX';

// Create new swift connection and authenticate
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.sendgrid.net', 25);
$transport ->setUsername($username);
$transport ->setPassword($password);
$swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message (subject)
$message = new Swift_Message($subject);

// add SMTPAPI header to the message
// *****IMPORTANT NOTE*****
// SendGrid's asJSON function escapes characters. If you are using Swift Mailer's
// PHP Mailer functions, the getTextHeader function will also escape characters.
// This can cause the filter to be dropped.
$headers = $message->getHeaders();
$headers->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', $hdr->asJSON());

// attach the body of the email
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
$message->setTo($to);
$message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');

// send message
if ($recipients = $swift->send($message, $failures))
{
// This will let us know how many users received this message
// If we specify the names in the X-SMTPAPI header, then this will always be 1.
echo 'Message sent out to '.$recipients.' users';
}
// something went wrong =(
else
{
echo "Something went wrong - ";
print_r($failures);
}
```

An idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a number of things causing this.  The most likely one is that your server has connecting to external hosts turned off.  Other possibilities are that you're using an old version of PHP that has an openSSL error or that you're being rate limited by something.

You should take a look at this question for details on the external host issue: [send mails via sendgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725365/send-mails-via-sendgrid)

---

On a separate note, you should use the SendGrid PHP library if you want to send emails using SendGrid.  It addresses a whole bunch of subtle nuances with Swift and sending in general.  Also, it gives you access to the HTTP API in case you can't use SMTP for whatever reason.

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

***Full Disclosure***: I work as a developer evangelist for SendGrid and work on the PHP library from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

for sendgrid might be two resons:

1. you may have the authentification data wrong
2. your account might still be provisioned, so you must wait a bit for it to be fully activated

so

- check all the autentification data from app/config/mail.php to match with the data from https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/index.html
- check also not the have a top message/notification on your sendgrid account like:

> Your account is still being provisioned, you may not be able to send
>   emails.

Comment: lol thnx, changed my mail password today >.< and I couldnt figure out the problem ^.-

Answer (score 0):

You will also receive this error if your account is frozen for billing reasons (e.g. lapsed credit card expiry date).

**Note:** SendGrid doesn't drop the message(s), they hold them until your billing issue is resolved then process them even when this error is returned.