# Swiftmailer Caught exception: Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, swiftmailer

I'm having trouble in symfony 1.4 swiftmailer .
When I try to use sendmail function() 
I got error code :

```
Caught exception: Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""
```

And symfony doesn't send messages.

Below is my function sendmail

```
static function sendmail($mail, $textmessage, $subject) {
    try {
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setFrom(sfConfig::get('app_mail_address_from'))
                ->setTo($mail)
                ->setSubject($subject)
                ->setBody($textmessage)
                ->setContentType("text/html");
      //  sfContext::getInstance()->getMailer()->send($message);
      sfContext::getInstance()->getMailer()->send($message);
    //   mail("mymailcom", "A subject", "A message", "FROM: noreply@mail.com");

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }


}
```

What I tried to do:

1. I tried to test mail() function. It works good.
2. I tried to change smtp settings to gmail account - not working

My Server is: CentOs6 on godaddy.co.uk server

Can somebody please help me with this error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158845/fatal-error-when-trying-to-send-email-using-swiftmailer-and-sendgrid

Answer (score 4):

Ok , post from comment helped, maybe somebody will use that:
I think the problem is swiftmailer:

```
 try {

        $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject')
            ->setFrom(sfConfig::get('app_mail_address_from'))
            ->setTo($mail)
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setBody($textmessage)
            ->setContentType("text/html");
        $mailer->send($message);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";die;
    }
```

This is working code

Comment: check your code, something is wrong at line noreply@gmail.com");